# How do I asynchronously get data from the database for a SwingWorker's publish method?

Tags: java, swing, hibernate, asynchronous, ejb

I have a remote EJB3 method that returns a `List<T>` from the DB using JTA (Hibernate).
Basicly it's just a simple HQL that looks something like this: `select t from T t where ...`.

This query takes a long time in some cases so I wanted to use a SwingWorker to asynchronously load chunks of the data into a JTable using the `publish` and `process` methods.
But, for that to work I also need to get the data in chunks from the server. right?
I can artificially divide the query into a number of "smaller" queries by setting some arbitrary range to them:
`select t from T t where ... and t.id < :rangeSrart and t.id > :rangeEnd`

But I was hoping there is a better way of doing that.
I looked at `@Asynchronous` but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.
Is there any way to do this with EJBs or anything else?

Comment: I think that is possible with paginations (`"smaller" queries`), but depends is if there (maybe there no) difference betweens time for whole query and first query from pagination, then you can to simulating pagination in doInBckground, create an batch and every 10 items push to publish(to the Swing GUI), sure everything here is only on academic level ....

Answer (score 0):

You need neither `publish` nor `process`. Simply get the list in your implementation of `doInBackground()`. Before start of `execute`() show an undetermined progress bar in a dialog. Also you should override `done()` to show your results and hide progress dialog.

Comment: But then the table will be filled only when the query is done, wouldn't it? I want the table to fill cumulatively so that the user doesn't need to wait to see at least some of the results.

Comment: It's not a Swing question. You need to load only first 100 records from the database, not the whole list. And load next chunk only when user want to see the next batch.